# Get nested data through Async pipe with Apollo client in Angular 2

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

I am trying to get data from this query:

```
const onInitQuery = gql`
query {
   library {
       files {
          name
          libraryPath
          id
          thumbFullPath
       }
      folders {
         id
         name
      }
   }
}
```

And I am following the example provided [here](http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/queries.html#select-pipe) but I don't know how to form my `*ngFor` loop. In the example he selects the first layer of the nested query through the select pipe but i need the folders property, which is nested in the second layer.

How would my `*ngFor` look like to make this happen? Atm it looks like this but this doesn't work:

```
  <div class="test" *ngFor="let folder of data | async | select: 'library.folders'">{{folder.name}}</div>
```

And my component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cv-library',
  templateUrl: './library.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./library.component.css']
})
export class LibraryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  public data: ApolloQueryObservable<any>;
  public folders: any;
  public files: any;

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.apollo.watchQuery({
      query: onInitQuery
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible right now to get nested values by specifying a path but you can create a PR for it. 

The code is https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular/blob/6fec002e5f1d0cc70029b94b7f7ddc53be4ac420/src/SelectPipe.ts#L14

Comment: It does support yet. You can check the source code https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular/blob/master/packages/apollo-angular/src/SelectPipe.ts

Comment: `Cannot find name 'ApolloQueryObservable'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apollo-angular` `SelectPipe` does not support get nested value yet. But you can implement this pipe by yourself. Here is my solution:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'select'
})
export class SelectPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(obj: any, name: string = '') {
    if (name && obj && obj.data) {
      return name.split('.').reduce((prev, curr) => {
        return prev ? prev[curr] : undefined;
      }, obj.data);
    }
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
  <div>
    <p>followers: </p>
    <ul *ngFor="let follower of data | async | select: 'user.followers.nodes'">
      <li>{{follower.name || follower.login}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

To get `data.user.followers.nodes` value.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best practice would be to do every transformation outside the template by not inventing the wheel and expose an Observable that returns exactly what your template needs.

```
<div>
  <p>followers: </p>
  <ul *ngFor="let follower of followers | async">
    <li>{{follower.name || follower.login}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the component class:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.apollo.watchQuery({
      query: onInitQuery
    })
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(
      map(result => ...)
    );
  }
```